# Stack Exchange API & User Profile

Tags: stackexchange-api

Is it possible to get user profile information such as GitHub, Twitter account names thru the API? This information is visible in the user profile page, I'd like to know if there is a way to access this information programatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this information is not available via the API. A [user object](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) only contains the following fields:

- about_me
- accept_rate
- account_id
- age
- answer_count
- badge_counts
- creation_date
- display_name
- down_vote_count
- is_employee
- last_access_date
- last_modified_date
- link
- location
- profile_image
- question_count
- reputation
- reputation_change_day
- reputation_change_month
- reputation_change_quarter
- reputation_change_week
- reputation_change_year
- timed_penalty_date
- up_vote_count
- user_id
- user_type
- view_count
- website_url

You *can* pull some profile information via the `about_me` and `website_url` fields, though.